# set value in javascript with using echo in php page

Tags: javascript, php

I've already retrieved a variable from user input in PHP and want to use as default value in another form as it's gonna displayed as follow:

```
$username = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username']);
echo'<script>document.getElementById("loginUsername").value ='.$username.' </script>';
```

but it's not working. kindly advise me on how to set a value of an element with a PHP variable in PHP page. Thank you

Comment: why are you doing this in php backend instead of in javascript frontend?

Comment: Check the spelling, JS is case-sensitive, and the echoed line contains multiple spelling errors. Also, PHP variables are not extracted inside single quotes, and if `$userName` is a string, it must be quoted correctly in JS. On the top of all that, inline scripts are bad practice, and forking them with PHP is even worse.

Comment: Does `Document.getElementByid("loginUsername").value =Steve` look like valid JS to you?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a templating language, and it has a nice shortcut for `echo`. Why not take the advantage of it? You don't need that JavaScript at all, instead, do something like this with PHP:

```
<?php
  $username = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username']);
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    ...
<input id="loginUsername" value="<?=$username?>">
```

Answer (score -1):

short answer : interchange single quote(') and double-quote(")

```
<input type="text" id='loginUsername'>

<?php
$username = "abc";
echo"<script>document.getElementById('loginUsername').value ='$username'</script>";
```

now it will work fine.

---

---

long answer: in PHP

```
$abc = 'qwerty/' . $name;
```

and

```
$abc = "qwerty/$name";
```

are same.

---

---

from PHP official website ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)
Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: What is `Document`? Quotes needed around js strings also

Comment: I update the code.  please check it. remember "JavaScript is case-sensitive"

Comment: for testing , I used $username = "abc"; you can use $username = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username']);